# Colunas de uma tabela se sobrescrevendo html

Tags: html, css

As colunas da tag table estao se sobrescrevendo.

Esta ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deveria ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
<table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td>fdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfs<br></td><td>fdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfsfdsdfsfdfsdisfsfhshfskdjhjksdhfdjskhfsdkjhfs<br></td></tr></tbody></table><p><br></p>
```

Aguardo ajuda... :D

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acrescentar esse CSS pra resovler esse problema:

```
.table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.table td {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Ainda nao funcionou :(